# Git says "nothing to commit, working tree clean" even after I've made local changes

Tags: git

I made a lot of changes to an index.html file and when I went to push it to the remote repo it says

> On branch master, Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.nothing to commit, working tree clean

Here is how it went down:

*Made changes to file*

then

`git status` returns

> On branch master - nothing to commit, working tree clean

then `git add .`

`git status` returns

> On branch master - nothing to commit, working tree clean

then `git commit -m "added bio"`

then `git status` returns

> On branch master - nothing to commit, working tree clean

then `git push origin master` returns

> Everything is up-to-date

I even tried `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master` and nothing. I'm certain I'm in the correct local repo and I'm certain I'm linked up to the correct remote repo because I've been pushing to that repo for a week with no problems. This issue came out of the blue.

Comment: What is the output of `git status --ignored`?

Comment: Have you actually saved the files?

Comment: @mkrieger1 same thing "On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Comment: @Pytth Yes. I save after every action.

Answer (score 2):

If you edited *index.html* and `git status` says the working tree is clean, then the *index.html* you edited is not in the working tree. To find out what working tree you are in, say `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. That is the git repo you are talking to. The *index.html* is evidently not in the working tree for that git repo (i.e. it is not in its containing folder or any subfolder thereof). If it *is* in the working tree, then it or a containing folder must be in the gitignores list.